# How to implement asynchronous image download with cache support in android?

Tags: android

I want to download all images from server and store it in a cache.In most of cases, downloaded images are directly bound to the imageView(e.g. Picasso). I want to use same functionalities in android which is provided by SDWebImage("https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage").

Comment: So did you try anything? Why can't you use Picasso library? Check this out http://square.github.io/picasso/ Another option could be https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I only want to store all images in cache but don't want images to directly bind with imageview. Both of these library set the images directly into imageview so those are not useful for me.

Comment: I guess you can modify this behavior. I am not sure.

Comment: Picasso lets you set the target to your own implementation of [Target interface](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html). This lets you choose how you want to use the Bitmap afterwards. Without setting it directly into an ImageView.

Comment: Using Picasso, How to create cache and store downloaded image directly into it instead of displaying with ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Shutterbug is a good library for this purpose (https://github.com/applidium/Shutterbug). I've used this myself in a few apps and it works well. You can either use the Shutterbug FetchableImageView (which extends ImageView and you give it a URL rather than a bitmap or resource ID and it will display the image when download is complete) or you can use the ShutterbugManager which allows you to control what happens after downloading and caching. All the caching is done for you, it's pretty awesome :)

There are good instructions on the GitHub page's README on how to use both, and there is a demo project too.

EDIT: Just noticed your comment. If you don't want to bind to an ImageView, you can use the ShutterbugManager to download the image and then do whatever with it. Any subsequent calls to the download method will fetch the image from the cache rather than doing an HTTP call again.

```
public void downloadImage(Context context, String url) {
    ShutterbugManager.getSharedImageManager(context).download(url, new ShutterbugManager.ShutterbugManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageSuccess(ShutterbugManager manager, Bitmap bitmap, String arg2) {
            // Do what you like with the Bitmap here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onImageFailure(ShutterbugManager arg0, String arg1) {
            // Failure :(
        }
    });
}
```